# Private Keyword in a C Struct

Tags: c, struct, keyword, private

Today, I have just noticed a statement in a C struct, and to be honest I was like WTF at first. It is like;

```
struct foo {
void *private;
//Some other members
};
```

Believe or not this struct is being compiled without any error. So what is the purpose of adding such a line (void *private)?

Comment: It's just the name of the variable, nothing related to visibility scope. `private` is not a reserved keyword in C, although it is in C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In pure C there's no `private` keyword, so the above is perfectly legal, albeit a very bad idea.

This would be invalid C++ though, and a C++ compiler would surely yield an error.

Comment: Allright this struct is in a header file but this struct is used in a c++ type class member function definition. For instance;
    MyClass::function () {
       struct foo Myfoo;
    }

Comment: @mecid are you using a C++ compiler or not? All else doesn't matter.

Comment: I am using waf automation tool. So I don't specifically use a compiler like gcc or g++ for my current job.

Answer (score 1):

`void*` are in C often used to hide the actual data type used, effectively hiding some implementation details from the interface.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have stumbled upon an important difference between C and C++, the way structures are implemented.

In C, structures contains can contain only primitive and composite datatypes, whereas C++ structures gives more functionality, since the structures in C++ are similar to classes than structures in C, hence they provide additional functionality such as

- Ability to classify members as private,public or protected.
- Can contain member functions.
- Structures in C++, can be used as a tool to enforce object oriented methods, since all OO functionality like inheritance, which is applicable to classes , holds good for structures as well.

So in short, the above code is valid C, but invalid C++.